# Finite normal subgroups of polycyclic-by-finite groups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a polycyclic-by-finite and $H<G$ a finite index subgroup. Let $F(G)$ be the unique maximal finite normal subgroup of $G$. Then $F(G)\cap H$ is finite and normal in $H$.

Question 1. Suppose $F(H)$ is non-trivial. Is $F(G)\cap H$ non-trivial?

Question 2. Is $F(G)\cap H=F(H)$?

Comment: I wonder whether the people who voted to close all find this problem easy to solve.

Comment: I seems that some people here systematically treat questions as standard exercises and close if there is not a detailed account of what the OP "tried"... which results in inaccurate closings when the question is rather of MathOverflow level (this question would be among the better half of the MO group theory questions, in my opinion).

Comment: (For an illustration see also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29945/kafkaesque-question-closures)

Comment: QMath, since the question is closed you might consider reasking on MathOverflow and I'll copy my answer there.

Comment: @YCor Since your answer gives a complete solution to my question, I don't see a reason to repeat the question on MathOverflow. Thank you!

Comment: Because on hold it's likely to be deleted while the interest of such threads is that they can be read (and sometimes discussed) years later by other users.

Comment: I an new here and didn't know it will be deleted. I will reask the question on MathOverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes (to both questions). It's essentially the contents of Proposition 2.7 in my commability Indiana UMJ paper ([arxiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.4194)), specified to (a particular instance of) discrete groups.

Here's a proof (easier in this case since we have discrete groups). In a group $G$ let $W(G)$ be its polyfinite radical, namely the subgroup generated by finite normal subgroups.

We need to know the following ($\ast$) : $W(G)$ is the set of torsion elements in $FC(G)$, the union of finite conjugacy classes of $G$.

> Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a finite index subgroup. Then $W(G)\cap H=W(H)$.

Proof: $\subset$ is clear. Conversely, let $F$ be a finite normal subgroup of $H$. Then clearly $F$ is contained in $FC(G)$, and also consists of torsion elements. Given the previous fact, it follows that $F$ is contained in $W(G)$. $\Box$

($\ast$) is an easy consequence of the fact that in an FC-group (group in which all conjugacy classes are finite), the set of torsion elements is closed under product. The latter fact is a bit harder (but well-documented).